# KineticJs: Use int or double?

Tags: javascript, html, kineticjs

I use KineticJS to make a lot of transformations. Like the following:

```
var baseX = pos.x;
var baseY = pos.y;
var w = self.getWidth();
var h = self.getHeight();
var halfW = w / 2;
var halfH = h / 2;
var aspectRadian = Math.atan2(halfH, halfW);
```

Pretty quickly you int numbers turn into double numbers. So how do I deal with it? For example when I have to set a position of a Rect. I do

```
rect.x(10);
```

Since there are no half pixel the following does not make any sense:

```
rect.x(10.3);
```

I guess that KineticJS makes a rounding internally or may be it works with double numbers.

**Is it better to use int numbers or double when working with KineticJS? Does one or the other solution leads to performance problems or rounding errors? Should I use double all the time to be as precise as possible?**

Comment: JavaScript always uses floats internally and KineticJS does not round to integers.  BTW, there actually ARE half-pixels--you can draw a rect with x=10.50 and it will appear on the half-pixel boundary on the display. Advice: don't bother adjust the coordinates.

Comment: @markE So should I always use double even when I start with an int number?

Comment: JavaScript internally casts all numbers as float. So if you supply an int [eg parseInt(20.22)], then your carefully boxed int will automatically turn into a very precise float (20.000000001). So don't bother doing any conversions. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you just plan on making calculations that use only pixels, then sticking to float (or double) is fine and shouldn't produce any issues (except for minor anti-aliasing, if that's an issue at all for you). But if, say, you're going to try to convert pixels into different measurements (e.g. inches), then you might find Javascript's floating point precision working against you.